# Where can I find an example of jQuery DataTables used with AJAX in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery, datatables

I am SO confused. I need to use jQuery DataTables to display large result sets (in excess of 1,000 rows). I have used DataTables successfully for smaller result sets, but trying to use it in AJAX is very, very tricky for me.

I have a Rails 3 controller method that responds to js. But I also have a matching .js.erb view template for that method. That template renders a partial which draws the table. What I really don't get is what in the hell the AJAX stuff from the DataTable is supposed to call.

Do I need ANOTHER method that is just supposed to return my JSON results for the DataTable? My existing POST to the method that ends up drawing the table has a serialized form as its input. Do I have to repost this to this other phantom method that I need to return the JSON results?

You see what a mess this is. So confusing. I really appreciate any help.